# Should the maximum number of request threads be similar to the maximum number of database connections?

Tags: tomcat, database, request

I have a spring boot application with an embedded tomcat server. The `max-threads` setting of `tomcat` is currently set to 250. Next to that the spring boot application also uses a `MySql` database as the `datasource`. For managing DB connections its using the `Hikari` connection pool that is set to a maximum of 10 database connections.

The maximum amount of concurrent request threads and the maximum amount of concurrent database connections differ a lot. My question is: Should I lower the `max-threads` setting to 10 so that each request will always have a database connection available?

I would also like to know what happens when all 10 request threads are taken and an 11th request comes in, will that request get bounced? If that is the case then maybe i should keep the `max-threads` setting a bit higher then 10.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can not give a general answer, but Atlassian recommends about 20% more database connections than max_threads. The given reason is, that the application may open additional database connections beside these caused by the http threads. So, I would say 'yes'.

If the database connections are exhausted, you will get an error message. If your application is robust against it, it may wait until one connection is released. If it is not robust against it, the application may crash. Confluence switches to error-mode. The user sees only an error screen.

If your max_threads are exhausted, the accept-queue is running full. If this is all full, you successfully put your server out of order.